# Rest API request payload

Tags: rest

I'm new to web services world. I have created a rest api in ERP software that creates sales order. How will anyone outside the world know what parameters to send to this and in what format ? From all the videos I have watched and all materials read they talk about no api documentation is needed as it is REST service, People just know what request payload to send. I m not sure if I understand how that is possible. Its like I give somebody the url and tell them go figure. I tried sending orders with different parameter list and it is creating errors. But, if I send it in the way it accepts then it is working fine. Not sure if I understand the concepts well. Should I be creating documentation of this api telling what the request payload should look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the academic definition of REST defined by Dr Fielding in his [dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf), it is true that such a service doesn't need any documentation. Hovewer, the chance are high that your service is not RESTful by his definition and that you need a documention to help your consumers. You can find an informative discussion about why a REST api doesn't need a documentation [here](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).

That being said, you will probably need a documentation in most case. Depending on your needs and consumers of your api, a simple text file could be enough; maybe a markdown that you can easily share with other developers. Just remember to add all information needed to understand each route (verb, path, query, body, response...), and you can even throw some example code to make it easy to start.

And if you need something more robust, I can only advise you to follow the [open api specification](http://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#openapi-document). One of the easiest way to get started is to use the [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io) . You will even be able to publish your documentation in a nice way using one of the many tools out there (ex: [redoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc)).

Writing a documention is never fun but nobody will use a product that they cannot understand, however great the product is.

Good luck,

Edit:

I rewrote the introduction as it was misleading, thanks to @Roman Vottner for pointing it out. THe previous intro was:

I don't know who told you that a documentation is not needed for a REST Api but I find this highly misleading for newcomers... A documentation is (super) important, especially if you are not the sole consumer of your API, and in that case I would say it's mandatory.

Comment: Thank You very much for your reply. This certainly answered my question.

Comment: Do you need a documentation if you interact with a HTML page? HTML is defined well enough so that any arbitrary Web client can make use of it. And HTML uses forms to "teach" clients about the properties a resource supports/expects and also about the target URI, the HTTP operation as well as the media type to use. So your answer, in the scope of REST, is completely wrong!

Comment: I am aware of the academic definition of REST, and I acknowledge that in this scope my answer is fundamentally wrong, but in the scope of the question I do think that I am in the right. I am pretty certain that @sam113 did not implement a true REST api as per Dr Fielding definition (please excuse if I am wrong) and my goal was to give him an helpful response to help him in his situation. The stamp REST is commonly used for non-REST api, and when answering a question I try to keep this in mind (to my knowledge, Dr Fielding was not able to provide an exemple of a true REST api implementation).

Comment: @Roman Vottner I have nevertheless edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

I completely disagree with the answer given by Joessel, which just propagates a typical RPC take on it, which is NOT REST at all!

In regards to how a service utilizing the REST architecture style should inform clients about what properties a resource supports and stuff like that, just look at traditional HTML pages. How are Web server able to tell your Browser what input it expects?

HTML is a media type that specifies the syntax to use as well as the semantics of each of the elements and attributes wich are admissible in a HTML document. I.e. [HTML Forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) enables a server to inform a client on the respective properties a resource support. In addition to that, a server also teaches a client on the respective target URI to send the request to, the HTTP operation to use upon sending the request as well as the media type to use for marshalling the request to a respective representation format. This is why you DON'T NEED any other documentation to interact with Web pages. Most arbitrary Web clients support HTML documents by default and therefore you don't need to reimplement the wheel to process such documents.

For non-HTML resources it is also just a matter of whether your client supports the respective media type or not. I.e. PNG files also follow a certain standard which allows arbitrary clients to show images instead of the actual bytes on your screen.

Most of those so called "REST APIs", which are truely RPC ones, just use custom JSON based message structures. [JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) itself just defines the basic syntax but no semantics for any elements, attributes or other properties. It doesn't even add support for links. [JSON Hyper-Schema](https://json-schema.org/) is an extension which at least triest o add support for it, though it already requires to use an other media type than `application/json`. Though, if such formats are not well-defined and standardized, widespread adoption will not be possible on the long run. Hence creating a common media type is of importance to increase interoperability for such media types. I.e. for JSON based formats, [HAL+JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08), [HAL Forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [ION](https://ionspec.org/#forms), and others provide definitions for basic JSON based message structures, with support for links and other features like form-support and other things.

So, if you take a closer look at the Web, you will find many concepts that you can reuse for a truely RESTful design. After all, REST just takes the ideas used on the Web for decades and attempts to offer the benefits resulting from these concepts to applications rather than humans alone. As such, it is always a good idea to first design the interaction flow as if one would interact with a traditional Web page and then take the concepts used in that design and apply it onto your application domain model.

As you don't need external documentation to interact with Web pages, so you don't need external documentation to interact with well defined message formats that follow a common media type as well. Through [content-type negotiation](https://www.w3.org/blog/2006/02/content-negotiation/) both server and client will communicate with representation formats both support. So, the more (different) media types you support, the more likely you will be in the end to interact with different parties in that environment and if all of the supported media types are standardized you might not need any external documentation at all.